# Running client side javascript without loading a new (blank) view on Odoo 8

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I need to run some client-side javascript from a button in a form view in Odoo 8. This button runs a python method which returns this dictionary:

```
{"type": "ir.actions.client",
 "tag": "my_module.do_something",}
```

do_something is defined in a .js file as follows:

```
openerp.my_module = function (instance) {
    instance.web.client_actions.add("my_module.do_something", "instance.my_module.Action");
    instance.my_module.Action = instance.web.Widget.extend({
        init: function() {
            // Do a lot of nice things here
        }    
    });
};
```

Now, the javascript is loaded and executed properly, but even before launching the init function, Odoo loads a brand new, blank view, and once the javascript is over I can't get browse any other menu entry. In fact, wherever I click I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callbackList' of undefined
```

What I need instead is to run the javascript from the form view where the button belongs, without loading a new view, so both getting the javascript stuff done and leaving all callbacks and the whole environment in a good state. My gut feeling is that I shouldn't override the init funcion (or maybe the whole thing is broken, I'm quite new to Odoo client-side js) , but I couldn't find docs neither a good example to call js the way I want. Any idea to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't work on v8 since a lot of time and I don't remember how to add that, but this might help you: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/doc/howtos/web.rst

Plus, if you search into v8 code base you can find some occurence of client actions in `web` module docs https://github.com/odoo/odoo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=instance.web.client_actions.add

Comment: Thanks simahawk, you made my day! The link to the search on github found many examples of what I needed and I have been able to fix my function. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointers simahawk posted in another answer, I have been able to fix my js, which is now doing exactly what I needed. For your reference, the code is as follows:

```
openerp.my_module = function (instance) {
    instance.web.client_actions.add("my_module.do_something", "instance.my_module.action");
    instance.my_module.action = function (parent, action) {
        // Do a lot of nice things here
    }
};
```